# Consulta Oracle forma tabular

Tags: sql, oracle

inicio en base de datos y tengo una duda, supongamos que tengo una tabla llamada MUNDO que tiene los siguientes valores:

[image: PAIS CONTINENTE]

Deseo obtener el siguiente resultado:

[image: CONSULTA]

Me podrían apoyar por favor orientar como se realizaría esa consulta, muchas gracias, les agradezco

La siguiente consulta:

```
select case when Pais is null then CONTINENTE else '    ' || Pais end as 
   Consulta
   from
  (
  select distinct CONTINENTE, null as Pais from PAIS
    union
  select CONTINENTE, Pais from PAIS
  ) D
```

Me devuelve de la siguiente manera:

[image]

Y buscaria que apareciera continente solo una vez, alguna sugerencia?

Al realizar el Query que indica Miguel:

```
select case when Pais is null then CONTINENTE else '    ' || Pais end as Consulta from ( select distinct CONTINENTE, null as Pais from PAIS    union select CONTINENTE, Pais from PAIS ) D;
```

Obtengo esto, solo que aparece al final de cada serie y no entiendo muy bien como lograr que aparezca al inicio

[image: El valor debería aparecer arriba]

Comment: @Flxtr he editado la pregunta a ver si es mas claro, muchas gracias

Comment: La imagen no tiene nada que ver con la consulta. Mas alla de eso, me gustaria aclarar que lo que queres hacer no tiene logica dentro de una base de datos. Estas tratando de solucionar un problema de vista, con una consulta que lo que devuelve es una serie de registros segun las restricciones que le pasas. Si, tal vez encuentres un query que lo haga, pero eso no es la funcionalidad de la base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esto:

```
 select case when Pais is null then Contiene else '    ' || Pais end as Consulta
    from
    (
    select distinct Contiene, null as Pais from ciudades
        union
    select Contiene, Pais from ciudades
    ) D
order by Continente, Pais nulls first
```

Si es Sql Server en lugar de Oracle simplemente cambia el || por +

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta, casi es lo que necesito, solo que se repite el continente y buscaria que salga una vez, alguna sugerencia?, he editado mi pregunta para poner el ejemplo – OrioonTV hace 10 minutos

Comment: @OrioonTV Puedes decirme exactamente la estructura de las tablas puesto que con el ejemplo que te pude debería de salirte únicamente el continente y debajo los paises

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel por tu tiempo, te comento que me di cuenta que las columnas estaban al revés, solo que me aparece al final de la serie el titulo y no entiendo muy buen como llevarlo al inicio, muchas gracias, he editado la información de mi pregunta para añadir lo que comento

Comment: Esto pasa porque Oracle a la hora de ordenar toma los nulos siempre como valor más grande y sql al revés...
Simplemente ponle un "order by Continente, Pais nulls first"

Answer (score 0):

prueba haciendo un **group by** de los continentes:

```
select case when Pais is null then CONTINENTE else '    ' || Pais end as 
 Consulta
 from
(
  select distinct CONTINENTE, null as Pais from PAIS
    union
    select CONTINENTE, Pais from PAIS
) D
GROUP BY CONTINENTE
```